# Numerical solution for inviscid Burgers' equation seems to have no breaking time?

Tags: python, finite-difference, nonlinear-equations, hyperbolic-pde

So I'm trying to use the Lax-Friedrichs method to solve the inviscid burgers' equation with initial condition $$u(x,0) = \sin(x)$$, using

$$u_m^{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(u_{m+1}^n + u_{m-1}^n) - \frac{\Delta t}{2 \Delta x}\left(\frac{(u_{m+1}^n)^2}{2} - \frac{(u_{m-1}^{n}) ^2}{2}\right)$$

I believe there should be a shock, so an essential break/discontinuity in the solution at $t=1$, going by [this answer on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2552151/995766), but my solution seems a little... smooth?

[image: At t = 1]

I'm adding a 3D plot as well for going through all times and it just seems kind of too continuous, but maybe I'm not interpreting the equation and its solution properly. [image: Lax Friedrichs solution]

The code I wrote for this (in Python) is below. I may not be implementing the method correctly, so I'd really appreciate if anyone had any feedback or could just go through it a bit and let me know where I may possibly be messing up.

```python
def LaxFriedrichs(x0, xf, Nx, t0, tf, Nt):
    x = np.linspace(x0, xf, Nx)
    t = np.linspace(t0, tf, Nt)
    dx = np.abs(x[1] - x[0])
    dt = t[1] - t[0]
    A = np.diag(np.ones(Nx - 2), 1) - np.diag(np.ones(Nx - 2), -1)
    A[0, -1] = -1
    A[-1, 0] = 1
    U = np.zeros((Nx, Nt))
    for i in range(len(x)):
        U[i, 0] = np.sin(x[i]) #initial condition
    B = np.diag(np.ones(Nx - 2), 1) + np.diag(np.ones(Nx - 2), -1)
    B[0, -1] = 1
    B[-1, 0] = 1
    B = 0.5 * B
    c = dt/(2*dx)
    def Uflux(U):
        return np.square(U)/2
    for k in range(Nt - 1):
        U[:-1, (k + 1):(k + 2)] = B @ U[:-1, k:(k + 1)] - c * A @ Uflux(U[:-1, k:(k + 1)])
        U[-1, :] = U[0, :]
    return t, x, U
```

**Edit:** Updated plot using a smaller $dx$ and $dt$ than before:

[image]

Is that a sort of shock at the 1.5-ish time mark?

**Another edit:** I think it works! Should have just looked at the 2-D plots and showed each point instead of allowing Python to draw a smooth curve haha

[image]

Comment: Wikipedia on Lax Friedrichs says "This method is conservative and first order accurate, hence quite dissipative". Perhaps the numerical dissipation has smeared out your shock?

Comment: @NNN that may be possible. I did, however, see this answer here (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2765034/995766) with slightly different initial conditions of course, but notice that there is definitely a break that's visible in their solution while using LF, yet when I change mine to the same condition, mine still seems too smooth? Comparing my code, I think it is pretty similar?

Comment: Interesting. The answer you linked says "... and converges to the correct shock profile as the grid is refined." Perhaps try refining the grid much more?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I actually did try that while experimenting with values of $dt$ and $dx$ and disregarded it as an unstable solution, but does it make it seem like there is a shock? (I've added an updated plot by using $dx \approx 0.0157$ and $dt = 0.005$.

Comment: There might be, but it's hard to see from the 3D figure.

Comment: How does it perform on a Riemann problem? i.e., a simple step function. In that case, the solution is analytically known and you can se the quality of the shock

Comment: @whpowell96 So I tried it on a Riemann problem, and I think I do see something, but I'm not sure if I'm interpreting the plot correctly. I did, however, check the above example again (and with a 1-cos(x) initial condition too), and notice a shock does form! So the code does seem alright!

Comment: @NNN I've added 2-D plots and I think it works!!